# How can I get a prompt to show up and fade away when I want using CSS transitions/animations?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a **Saved** prompt that gets displayed whenever an inline edit is made to a form. Whenever an edit is made, I want the prompt to appear at full opacity and then fade away over 2 seconds. The one extra stipulation I have is that if the transition/animation is not completely finished and the prompt is triggered again, I need to instantly redisplay the prompt with full opacity (and then fade it out again over 2 seconds).

I don't have any major browser restrictions, as IE9 is the minimum requirement.

Is this possible using a combination of CSS transitions/animations and JS, and if so, how should I do it?

Just to note, I've tried multiple things thus far that have gotten me partway there, but they all seem to have one issue or another, so I was hoping that there is some common solution to this problem that someone could please teach me.

Thank you.

---

**Edit**: KatieK, thank you for your offer to help, and sorry for the delayed response. My code is essentially the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Animation example</title>
    <style>
      p {
        background: green;
        opacity: 0;
      }

      .show {
        -webkit-animation: fade_out 2s;
        -moz-animation: fade_out 2s;
        animation: fade_out 2s;
      }

      @-webkit-keyframes fade_out {
        0% {
          opacity: 1.0;
        }

        25% {
          opacity: 1.0;
        }

        100% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }

      @-moz-keyframes fade_out {
        0% {
          opacity: 1.0;
        }

        25% {
          opacity: 1.0;
        }

        100% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }

      @keyframes fade_out {
        0% {
          opacity: 1.0;
        }

        25% {
          opacity: 1.0;
        }

        100% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }

      div {
        border: #000 solid 1px;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="prompt">Saved</p>
    <div id="editable" contenteditable="true">
    </div>
    <script>

      document.getElementById('editable').onblur = function () {
        document.getElementById('prompt').className = '';
        document.getElementById('prompt').offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById('prompt').className = 'show';
      };

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I read on several sites that once an animation is triggered, you cannot retrigger the animation without causing some sort of page reflow, which is what the offsetHeight property line does.

This solution does work, but it feels really hacky to me, so I was simply wondering if there is a more solid way to achieve what I want, which is what the code above does, but without the hackiness.

Thank you.

Comment: If you post a demo with your markup, CSS and any JS libraries, we can help you go from there.

Answer (score 1):

IE9 doesn't support CSS3 animations (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation), so you'll need a JavaScript assist. Modernizr or jQuery are popular options - which to use depends on your exact scenario.